# Design pattern for a calculation that has to output a report in Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I have a class that does calculations. Most of the times it is used in the code to output a single value:

Use: `value = Calculator.new(1234).output`

This is an example of the class definition:

```
class Calculator

  def initialize(parameter_1)
    @parameter_1 = parameter_1
  end

  def output 
    op_1_result = operation_1(@parameter_1)
    op_2_result = operation_2(op_1_result)

    operation_3(op_2_result)
  end

  def operation_1(param)
  ...

end
```

But sometimes the user has to print a report of the calculation, showing many of the variables from inside the calculations.

The first solution I implemented was to pass a parameter at initialization telling the class that it should save some internal variables for the report, like this:

```
class Calculator

  attr_reader :report

  def initialize(parameter_1, reporting=false)
    @parameter_1 = parameter_1
    @reporting = reporting
    @report = {}
  end

  def output 
    op_1_result = operation_1(@parameter_1)
    @report[:op_1_result] = op_1_result if @reporting

    op_2_result = operation_2(op_1_result)
    @report[:op_2_result] = op_2_result if @reporting

    operation_3(op_2_result)
  end

  def operation_1(param)
  ...

end
```

Then, when I want to get those intermediate variables, I would:

```
calculator = Calculator.new(1234, true) # reporting activated
report = calculator.report

report[:op_1_result] # one of the intermediate variables of the calculation
```

Does this break the single responsibility principle, as the class is now calculating the value and reporting at the same time?

Is there a better way to do this, a design pattern where I could have a fast calculation of the output result where it is needed and show the report where needed without all those ifs?

Any light on this and comments will be really appreciated!

---

Obs (another discussion): I've read that a more functional approach to just outputting a value would be a great thing. But that kept me wondering about how to show those internal intermediate values when needed. How do more functional programmers would do it...?

Answer (score 2):

I guess "builder pattern" is suitable and "report pad" should be injected from outside.

```
class Calculator

  def initialize(*parameters)
    @parameters = parameters
  end

  def report_to(report_pad)
    @report_pad = report_pad
    self
  end

  def output()
    ret = @parameters[0].to_i + @parameters[1].to_i 
    report('Did p0  + p1')

    ret
  end

  private

  def report(message)
    @report_pad << "\n".prepend(message) if @report_pad.respond_to? '<<'
  end

end

####

reports = ""

result = Calculator
  .new(1, 2)
  .report_to(reports)
  .output()

puts result, reports
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make all intermediate results public methods and chain the results in the final output?

Perhaps something like this:

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(parameter)
    @parameter = parameter
  end

  def output 
    op_3_result
  end

  def op_1_result
    @op_1_result ||= operation_1(parameter)
  end

  def op_2_result
    @op_2_result ||= operation2(op_1_result) 
  end

  def op_3_result
    @op_3_result ||= operation3(op_2_result) 
  end

  private

  def operation1(arg)
    # ...
  end

  def operation2(arg)
    # ...
  end

  def operation3(arg)
    # ...
  end

  attr_reader :parameter
end
```

That would allow you to call whatever you need on the same instance:

```
calculator = Calculator.new(1234)
calculator.output       #=> the final result
calculator.op_2_result  #=> the intermediate result of step 2
```

Comment: Hey spickelmann, thanks. I understand. That's a lot cleaner. But that would instantiate all those values for all those times where I just want to get the output value. Wouldn't it be memory expensive? (My report has a lot of intermediate variables).

Comment: Yes, it would store all values as long as your calculator instance is assigned to a variable. Is that need memory? Sure. It really depends on the number of calculations and steps. In the above examples we are talking about some bytes, how many steps does your calculator have and is using a few kb more memory really an issue on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different pattern with `Report` being its own class and allow it to just pass through when reporting is turned off.  Here is a simple example:

```
class Calculator
  attr_reader :report
  def initialize(parameter_1, reporting=false)
    @parameter_1 = parameter_1
    @report = Report.new(reporting)
  end
  def output 
    op1 = operation_1(report.capture(:param1,@parameter_1))
    report.capture(:op1,op1)
    op2 = report.capture(:op2) { operation_2(op1) }
    operation_3(op2)
  end
  def operation_1(param);
    param + 7
  end
  def operation_2(param); 
    param - 3
  end
  def operation_3(param); 
    param * 2
  end
end

class Report
  attr_reader :reporting, :reportables
  def initialize(reporting)
    @reporting = reporting
    @reportables = {}
  end
  def capture(key, val=nil,&block)
    warn "Block supercedes value" if val && block_given?
    result = block_given? ? block.call : val  
    @reportables[key] = result if reporting
    result
  end 
  def [](key)
    return 'No Reporting' unless reporting
    @reportables[key]
  end
end
```

Then you can use like so

```
c = Calculator.new(12)
c.output 
#=> 32
c.report[:op1] 
#=> "No Reporting"

c = Calculator.new(12, true)
c.output 
#=> 32 
c.report[:op1] 
#=> 19
c.report[:param1]
#=> 12
```

This way each step can use a block for more complicated items where the result should be captured or just pass a value if you choose and intermediate steps like `operation_3` (in this case) that do not need to be "captured" can just flow through.

If reporting is off then everything just flows through and the captures are ignored.

Your `#output` method could also look like this (no intermediate locals at all although it does hurt the readability a bit)

```
  def output 
    operation_3 (
      report.capture(:op2,
        operation_2(
          report.capture(:op1) do 
            operation_1(report.capture(:param1,@parameter_1))
          end   
        )
      )
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dependency injection like this:

```
class Calculator

  def initialize(parameter_1, reporter = nil)
    @parameter_1 = parameter_1
    @reporter = reporter
  end

  def output 
    op_1_result = call_with_reporting :operation_1, @parameter_1
    op_2_result = call_with_reporting :operation_2, op_1_result

    operation_3(op_2_result)
  end

  def operation_1(param)
    ...
  end

  def call_with_reporting(operation, *args)
    result = self.send(operation, *args)
    @reporter.report(operation, result) if @reporter
    result
  end
end

class ConsoleReporter
  def initialize
    @results = {}
  end

  def report(operation, result)
    @results[operation] = result
  end

  def run_report
    puts @operations
  end
end
```

Now you can use Calculator like this:

```
reporter = ConsoleReporter.new
Calculator.new(12, reporter).output
reporter.run_report
```

Later you can use Calculator with other format reporter (like ToFileReporter)